# How to make beautiful vertical borders in tables

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

I want to print a table with vertical lines. This is what I currently have:

```
% Preamble: \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccccccccc|}
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{U-Net} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{FC-DenseNet} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DeepLabv3+} \\
\cmidrule(r){3-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-8} \cmidrule(l){9-10}
& & 256 & 512 & 1024 & 256 & 512 & 1024 & 256 & 512\\
\cmidrule(r){3-10}
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{U-Net}}        & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{512}  & 1 & & & & & & &\\[5pt]
                                                        & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{1024} & 1 & 1 & & & & & &\\[7pt]
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{FC-DenseNet}}  & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{256}  & 0.1 & 1 & 1 & & & & &\\[5pt]
                                                        & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{512}  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & & &\\[5pt]
                                                        & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{1024} & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 & & &\\[7pt]
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{DeepLabv3+}}   & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{256}  & 0.008 & 0.378 & 0.785 & 1 & 1 & \textless 0.001 & &\\[5pt]
                                                        & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{512}  & \textless 0.001 & 0.007 & 0.078 & 0.544 & 1 & \textless 0.001 & 0.569 &\\[5pt]
                                                        & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{1024} & 0.146 & 0.243 & 0.436 & 1 & 1 & \textless 0.001 & 1 & 1\\[5pt]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

producing this table:
[image: Current table]

You might already guess that I would like to have one solid outer box. But most importantly, I would like to have the same style as the header at the left side, i.e., something similar to `\cmidrule` but producing lines across multiple rows of the table.

Comment: The booktabs package regards vertical lines as declasse.    Use \cline instead.

Comment: Booktabs: "You should not use vertical rules in tables, end of story."

Comment: Avoid sideways text.....

Comment: you have not mentioned booktabs or provided an example people can run, but see the booktabs package documentation._by design_ it makes vertical rules unusable

Comment: Well, then I guess the problem is not solvable.

Comment: Not with `booktabs`, no. Why again do you need vertical rules in the first place? They add nothing to your tables.

Comment: I would argue that the sideways text is making your table harder to understand.  "DeepLabv3+" runs into "FC-DenseNet", and the numbers are too close to easily read.

Comment: The sideways text might be better in separate `\fbox`es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tabularray`, two cases:

- texts in the first two columns are rotated
- rotated text is only int first column

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec= {|Q[c,m]|*{9}{X[c,m]}|},
             colsep=4pt
             }
    \toprule
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  U-Net
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  FC-DenseNet
                    &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}  DeepLabv3+
                        &                                   \\
    \cmidrule[r]{3-5} \cmidrule[lr]{6-8} \cmidrule[l]{9-10}
    &   & 256 & 512 & 1024 & 256 & 512 & 1024 & 256 & 512   \\
    \cmidrule{3-10}
\SetCell[r=2]{c}  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{U-Net}        
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{512}  
        & 1 & & & & & & &           \\
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{1024} 
        & 1 & 1 & & & & & &         \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[r=3]{c}    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{FC-DenseNet}
     & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{256}  
        & 0.1   & 1  & 1 & & & & &  \\
     & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{512}  
        & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & & &     \\
     & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{1024} 
        & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 
        & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 &   &   &   \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[r=3]{c}    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{DeepLabv3+}   
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{256}  
        & 0.008 & 0.378 & 0.785 & 1 & 1 & \textless 0.001 & &   \\
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{512}  
        & \textless 0.001 & 0.007 & 0.078 & 0.544 
        & 1 & \textless 0.001 & 0.569 &             \\
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{1024} 
        & 0.146 & 0.243 & 0.436 & 1 & 1 & \textless 0.001 & 1 & 1\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {|Q[c,m]|*{9}{X[c,m]}|},
              colsep = 4pt,
            row{3-Y} = {rowsep=0.5pt},
               vspan = even}
    \toprule
    &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  U-Net
            &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  FC-DenseNet
                        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}  DeepLabv3+
                                    &                       \\
    \cmidrule[r]{3-5} \cmidrule[lr]{6-8} \cmidrule[l]{9-10}
    &   & 256 & 512 & 1024 & 256 & 512 & 1024 & 256 & 512   \\
    \cmidrule{3-10}
\SetCell[r=2]{c}  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{U-Net}
    & 512
        & 1 & & & & & & &           \\
    & 1024
        & 1 & 1 & & & & & &         \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[r=3]{c}    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{FC-DenseNet}
     & 256 
        & 0.1   & 1  & 1 & & & & &  \\
     & 512
        & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & & &     \\
     & 1024
        & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001
        & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 &   &   &   \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[r=3]{c}    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{DeepLabv3+}
    & 256
        & 0.008 & 0.378 & 0.785 & 1 & 1 & \textless 0.001 & &   \\
    & 512
        & \textless 0.001 & 0.007 & 0.078 & 0.544
        & 1 & \textless 0.001 & 0.569 &             \\
    & 1024
        & 0.146 & 0.243 & 0.436 & 1 & 1 & \textless 0.001 & 1 & 1\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

Answer (score 3):

If the middle vertical line is not important, you could add a frame around the whole `tabular`:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{\heavyrulewidth}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \fbox{%
        \begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
        \addlinespace[3pt]
        & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{U-Net}
            & \multicolumn{3}{c}{FC-DenseNet}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DeepLabv3+} \\
        \cmidrule(r){3-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10}
        & & 256 & 512 & 1024 & 256 & 512 & 1024 & 256 & 512\\
        \cmidrule(r){3-10}
        \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{U-Net}} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{512}  & 1 &   &&&&&&\\[5pt] & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{1024} & 1 & 1 &&&&&&\\[7pt]
        \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{FC-DenseNet}} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{256}  & 0.1 & 1 & 1 &   &&&&\\[5pt]
            & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{512}  & 1   & 1 & 1 & 1 &&&&\\[5pt]
            & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{1024} & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 & \textless 0.001 & & &\\[7pt]
        \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{DeepLabv3+}}
            & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{256}  & 0.008 & 0.378 & 0.785 & 1 & 1 & \textless 0.001 & &\\[5pt]
            & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{512}  & \textless 0.001 & 0.007 & 0.078 & 0.544 & 1 & \textless 0.001 & 0.569 &\\[5pt]
            & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{1024} & 0.146 & 0.243 & 0.436 & 1 & 1 & \textless 0.001 & 1 & 1\\[5pt]
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```